# who has the best online prep MCSE study materials?

Tags: untagged

I'm studying for my Microsoft Certified Systems Engineer (MCSE) on my own and was wondering who you could recommend for study materials?  I did shell out a bunch of money for a local class and when it came to taking the test, there were a slew of topics which weren't even covered.  For example, in my 070-293 test, they didn't even touch such as Certificates, how to setup clusters, sql server clustering, etcs.  I realize there is a bunch out there such as cbtnuggets, preplogic, etcs.

Which online preps do you suggest best preps you for the tests before I spend any more money on this stuff?

thanks in advance

Comment: this could actually be sysadmin related, as MCSE is certainly a certification for microsoft-oriented sysadmins..

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but I wouldn't bother with the MCSE, the new certification for 2008 and 2008 R2 is the MCITP. the shelf life of 2003 and it's MCSE cert are expiring kind of soon in most people's minds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way also happens to be free... (and you'll know what you're doing when you're done!)

http://blogs.technet.com/seanearp/archive/2007/04/27/what-s-the-best-way-to-become-certified.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use [TestKing](http://www.testking.com/) and [Cramsession](http://www.cramsession.com). They both have nice "summarized" documents about the subjects. TestKing also has CheatSheets in which they give you actual questions and answers from the actual exams, but some might consider that to be cheating without learning anything.

I would stick to the summaries, which will allow you to get more knowledge in a shorter period of time.

Answer (score 0):

[Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/certprep/microsoft/mcse-2003.kap) has study guides, sample test questions, flash cards, and links to training. It is not free, but they have a lot of good info and their sample tests are verify similar to the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not online, but I find [Microsoft Press books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Microsoft+Press&x=0&y=0) to be the most reliable study materials.